# cakephp 3.6 CSRF token mismatch in post request

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.6

When I submit I Will get following error.

[image]

I have loaded CSRF Component.

Let me know why this error coming.

Thanks

Comment: Did you submit your form using ajax?

Answer (score 0):

According to the stacktrace you are using both, the CSRF middleware (see `src/Application.php`) and the CSRF component (see `src/Controller/AppController.php`) - you should use only one of them! The component is deprecated, so ideally use the middleware.

If you have both enabled, then the CSRF middleware will be invoked first, and after validating the submitted token, it will unset it from the request data, so that the subsequent token check in the CSRF component will fail with the error that you are seeing.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Middleware > Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Middleware](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/middleware.html#csrf-middleware)**
- **[Cookbook > Controllers > Components > Cross Site Request Forgery](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/csrf.html)**
- **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/12453**